# I am working on a SQL query to filter the category based on the oldest datetime of its respective fruit. I am unsure how to put this condition in SQL

Tags: sql

| Food | category | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | morning | 2021-10-06 00:00:00 |
| Apple | Afternoon | 2021-10-06 01:00:00 |
| Apple | Night | 2021-10-06 02:00:00 |
| Dates | Brunch | 2021-10-06 10:00:00 |
| Dates | Snack | 2021-10-06 17:00:00 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want :

```
select t.*
from(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by food order by datetime) as seq
     from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this results

Here is the firs one that came to mind for me:

```
SELECT 
    Food
FROM 
    myTable
GROUP BY 
    Food
HAVING MIN(DateTime)
```

This uses and aggregate function in the HAVING clause to find the MIN(aka oldest) datetime